# Excel Function - How to excluding certain alphabetically

Tags: excel

I am using the following function to build a series of running number in an excel file.

"=LEFT(ADDRESS(ROW(AA1),COLUMN(AA1)+(ROW(A1:A1)-1),4),2)"

The lists shown in the file is look similar like:
AA,AB,AC,AD,...

[image]

Now, I am trying to exclude certain alphabetical (such as "G, I, O") from the list, but I do not know how to start it.

Any Advise?

Remarks: exclude (G, I, O) -> "AG,AI..,GA,GB...OZ"

Thanks.

Comment: From your given formula, it would seem that the output is to go into more than one row.
Can you clarify what should be returned in the first row? And the second?
Also, what is the final output to be? ZZ?

Comment: Yes the output should be row row by row, and AA will be the first row at the top, whereas the final row will be the ZZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set cell A1 to `"AA"`.

In cell A2 put the following formula:

```
=IF(FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")=LEN("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",FIND(LEFT(A1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")+1,1)&"A",LEFT(A1,1)&MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",FIND(RIGHT(A1,1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")+1,1))
```

You can then just drag this down to how many ever rows you need. It might look complicated, but it is really simple if you break it down.

To exclude certain chars like "G", "I" and "O", just remove them from everywhere you see `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. So this would become `"ABCDEFHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. It might be better to put this list of chars into another cell and then just reference that cell instead of repeating the string so many times in the formula.

Comment: Yes, this solution help me a lot. Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 1):

First go to *Name Manager* and define:

*Name:* `List`

*Refers to:* `={"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"H";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z"}&{"A","B","C","D","E","F","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}`

Then put this formula in your first cell of choice:

`=INDEX(List,CEILING(ROWS($1:1)/COUNTA(INDEX(List,1)),1),1+MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,COUNTA(INDEX(List,1))))`

and copy down a further 528 rows.

Regards

Comment: Hi XOR LX, Thank you for the advise. I manage to create the Manager and its comment works. whereas during I put in the formula in my first cell, it will show a blue line and it give me "0" when I copy down to several rows. :)